# Are the String lliterals stored in the string pool unique?

Tags: java, string, jls

I understand that Strings may be interned, but it it an action that is performed religiously when a new string object is created?

Jls section 3.10.5 string literals.

Comment: @Chin. `String x="zzz"` does not create a new string object.

Comment: what I meant is that once you compile, you can't create new string literals, as it's only a string literal if it was in the source code.

Comment: Does String x = "zzz" imply that "zzz" string literal is created in the String pool and referenced to x?

Comment: Yes, that's right. We'd say "referenced *by* x", but I think you understand the principle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All `String` *literals* go into the string pool. Otherwise, your application must call `intern()` on the `String`, or it won't go into the pool.

A `String` literal is a string that appears in source code with double quotes around it:

```
String greeting = "Hello, ";
String s = greeting + name;
```

In this example, `"Hello, "` is a literal string. It is in the intern pool. It is also referenced by the variable `greeting`.

The `String` referred to by `s` is not a literal, and is not in the intern pool… unless you make this call:

```
s = s.intern();
```

Comment: Hi Erickson, insightful, am  i right to say that intern pool == string pool?

Comment: @ChinBoon yes, the only `String` pool used by the runtime is the intern pool.